# Functional Banana Traveller - Broken Type Mystery

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

I'm getting the following error:

```
Libraries/Reactive/GameMechanic.hs:34:80:
No instance for (Apply (Behavior t0) (Event t))
  arising from a use of `<@'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Apply (Behavior t0) (Event t))
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `(updateAgentMap <$> bHyperMap <*> bPlanetMap) <@ eTick'
In the expression:
  accumB initialAMap
  $ (updateAgentMap <$> bHyperMap <*> bPlanetMap) <@ eTick
In an equation for `bAgentMap':
    bAgentMap
      = accumB initialAMap
        $ (updateAgentMap <$> bHyperMap <*> bPlanetMap) <@ eTick
```

The `t0` in the `Event` and the `t1` in the `Behavior` is my clue as to the problem, but I don't know how to interpret this clue. So let's start with some types, the errant code and my reasoning as to why it should work.

```
bAgentMap :: Behavior t AgentMap
bAgentMap = accumB initialAMap $ (updateAgentMap <$> bHyperMap <*> bPlanetMap) <@ eTick
```

`initialAMap :: AgentMap`

`updateAgentMap :: HyperMap -> PlanetMap -> AgentMap -> AgentMap`

`bHyperMap :: Behavior t HyperMap`

`bPlanetMap :: Behavior t PlanetMap`

`accumB :: a -> Event t (a -> a) -> Behavior t a`

So I've got the first parameter covered, `AgentMap`. The second one needs to be `Event t (AgentMap -> AgentMap)`. How to get there? If I begin with `updateAgentMap <$> bHyperMap`, the type should be `Behavior t (PlanetMap -> AgentMap -> AgentMap)`. Okay one more parameter `updateAgentMap <$> bHyperMap <*> bPlanetMap` gives us a type `Behavior t (AgentMap -> AgentMap)`. Almost there right?

Given this
`(<@) :: f a -> g b -> g a`
and
`eTick :: Event t ()`

and substituting `a` for `(AgentMap -> AgentMap)`
I should be able to do this
`(updateAgentMap <$> bHyperMap <*> bPlanetMap)` <@ eTick

to get `Event t (AgentMap -> AgentMap)`

But not so fast. My reasoning must be failing somewhere. Could someone tell me where?

Update: It turns out this problem occurred because eTick was not defined (I think). I had attempted to separate much of the code out into it's own [file](https://github.com/mlitchard/emporos/blob/devel/Libraries/Reactive/GameMechanic.hs). I knew leaving eTick `undefined` wouldn't be satisfactory, but I haven't worked out what I want to do about this. So in the meantime I started moving code into a [let](https://github.com/mlitchard/emporos/blob/devel/Libraries/Reactive/GameLoop.hs) binding as I originally had. Now my code compiles. I don't want the `let` bindings to stay there for long. My expectation is that a revisit to the [breakout](https://github.com/bernstein/breakout) project will show me how to better structure my code.

Comment: From the type error, the t in Behavior t (AgentMap -> AgentMap) is different than the t in eTick's type. The most likely cause is that one of your definitions is more polymorphic than it should be. Perhaps you've defined something using let? You can try turning on scoped type variables and adding explicit types to force the ts to be the same.

Comment: Could you add code for `bHyperMap` and `bPlanetMap`

Comment: As Jason said, your reasoning is mostly correct, but the type error is due to the type parameter `t` being different for `bHyperMap` and `eTick`. You need to post a larger code sample and show the context in which `eTick` and `bAgentMap` and `bHyperMap` are defined to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. More code being posted later today. Work has been rather involved these past few days.